# Getting Bluetooth working in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

My first go with Ionic plugins. Got a PaypalHere pad machine I am trying to link up to my app, which uses Bluetooth. So will later need to enter a Mac address for that somewhere. But just need to get Bluetooth working first.

I have installed Bluetooth using "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial" 
https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

I originally installed npm inistall -g cordova but now see refs on tutorials to ngcordova?

Can anyone help with what I need to add to my app.js file(controller) now to get a prompt that Bluetooth is working and fully enable Bluetooth?

I assume i need to inject the service in the controller then run some function to perform a check.

There is a post here but it doesn't seem to be complete
[BluetoothSerial plugin is not working with ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999759/bluetoothserial-plugin-is-not-working-with-ionic)

Here is my app.js code:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'home-tab' : {
         templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.list', {
      url: '/list',
      views: {
        'list-tab' : {
         templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
         controller: 'ListController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.detail', {
      url: '/list/:aId',
      views: {
        'list-tab' : {
         templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
         controller: 'ListController'
        }
      }
    })

      // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');

})

.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {
        $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.orders = data;
          $scope.whichorder = $state.params.aId;
        });
}]);
```

***I am perfoming this in Chrome browser on a PC***

Comment: Well, firstly even though I installed the Bluetooth via command line. Looks like I need to install ngCordova too. So I did this here http://pointdeveloper.com/what-is-ngcordova-how-to-use-it-with-ionic/  - Still need a bluetooth function check in this app.js file though and perhaps on controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#enable) and create a function like this in your controller:

```
enableBluetooth() {
    bluetoothSerial.enable(
        function () {
            alert("Bluetooth is enabled");
        },
        function () {
            alert("The user did *not* enable Bluetooth");
        }
    );
}
```

Now you can call the `enableBluetooth()` method for example from a button click event like so:

```
<button ng-click="controller.enableBluetooth()">Enable Bluetooth</button>
```

After clicking the button and accepting the success-callback should alert that Bluetooth is enabled. Add your code to execute in here after making sure it works.

Note two things here:

1. `controller` is the name of my controller in the correspoding view.
2. Of course you don't have to trigger the `enableBluetooth()` method by a button click, this is just an example. Feel free to adjust this to your needs.

---

On the long run you might want to think on creating a (bluetooth) service and putting all bluetooth related code there. Just search for *Angular services*, there a lot of good tutorials out there and also here on SO. But I strongly recommend to get it working first ;)

---

Additional information:
Got this simple example working on my Android 6 device, make sure the plugin supports your platform (browser) as well!